Bind query in Office 365 is adding external users and shouldn't
I have this Bind query tied to a dynamic distribution list:
 ((((((((((((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (-not(Name -like 'SystemMailbox{*')))) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'MailboxPlan')))) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'SharedMailbox')))) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'DiscoveryMailbox')))) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'ArbitrationMailbox')))) -and (-not(Name -like 'SystemMailbox{*')) -and (-not(Name -like 'CAS_{*')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'MailboxPlan')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'DiscoveryMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'PublicFolderMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'ArbitrationMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'AuditLogMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'AuxAuditLogMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'SupervisoryReviewPolicyMailbox')))

The problem is the definition includes external users in the distribution list, and we don't want them there.
How can I add to this to say (-not(EXTERNAL USERS)) in addition to what is already being filtered out?
Thanks
